# Could not load file or Assembly with embedded Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-assembly, resx

I'm getting an odd error when accessing embedded resources in an assembly that I've created when it's called from a WinForms app.

Basically I have an assembly that contains a single standard resource file (`Resources.resx`) in the `Properties` folder. The assembly is `Westwind.RazorHosting`, so the resources are generated into `Westwind.RazorHosting.Properties`. I access the resources using the generated designer class (`Resources.Designer.cs`) only from within the assembly code.

When I run tests against the project a test project all is well. Errors (which are the main source of resources used in the app) display properly.

However, when the WinForms app calls the app and causes an error, resource access fails. The error is:

> Could not load assembly (Westwind.RazorHosting.resources) or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Notice that it's not pointing at `Westwind.RazorHosting.Properties.resources`, but at `Westwind.RazorHosting.resources`.

When I step into this code with the debugger I step straight into the generated `Resources.designer.cs` class and the `ResourceManager` there looks perfectly fine - there's a reference and it points at the right namespace internally. I'm running in the default en-US locale. I checked the assembly generated and the resources do exist under the proper/expected resource id (ie. `Westwind.RazorHosting.Properties.ResourceId`) - they are present.

Any idea what could be causing .NET to look in the wrong place for resources?